# Change Div Style by using JavaScript without page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am tried to change the background color for div by using JavaScript, but the changes didn't applied because when I press on button
the browser make reload for the page and restore to default setting without change.

How I can change the background color for div without page reload or the changes applied?

Comment: It is possible, you only need to give the markup first

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't post it.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue. If you are using Chrome use Incognito mode. This will clear your cache each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code using jQuery that changes the background without reloading:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Changing DIV Background Color</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #changing_background {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 200px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="changing_background"></div>

<button id="change_background">Click Me</button>

<script>
  $("#change_background").click(function(e){
    $("#changing_background").css("background-color", "blue");
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Page reloads because your button is inside a form and when you click it - you submit the form.

Inside the `onclick` function you need to prevent default action, just end with:

```
return false;
```

If you ask why: `submit` is default button type:

> **Button types**:
>
> - submit: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specified**, or if the attribute is
>   dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
> - reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
> - button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are
>   triggered when the events occur.

Recommended readings:

- [HTML Button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)
- [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: That's only true for a submit button

Comment: For any button - [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/gdb37t5h/)

Comment: Interesting catch, but not "any button".  `input type='button'` and `button type='button'` [do not behave that way](http://jsfiddle.net/gdb37t5h/1/).

Comment: `input type='button'` is an `<input>` tag, I'm talking about `<button>` html tags. If you put a button inside the form it will act as submit button, unless you change its purpose.

Comment: Fair enough, a little presumptuous IMO but then again the OP didn't give much to go off.  At any rate, yes, the default button will act as a submit but merely setting the type will do the same thing while being more semantic.  I'm exactly disagreeing with you, but I think this context was necessary.  Btw that link might render this question a dupe.

Comment: Well, only MDN says it is default type for button, think 10 years ago it was different and some of browsers did not submit the form if type was not specified to `submit` (thinking of IE). Or even if you specify `submit` it would not submit the form, you would have to use an `input` tag or script.